# Product selection grid while placing order from admin section

Tags: magento

While placing order manually from admin section of magneto there is product selection grid comes in the process. I am trying to find out code/file within magneto files which is originating this grid but still no success.

Please suggest how can I find this.

Actually, I wanted to to call a JavaScript function on the click of selection of product row but not getting the code file where I need to add this function. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of view Blocks :

- Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Items for the product selection grid
- Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Items_Grid for the already selected products grid

In terms of view template files :

- app/design/adminhtml/default/default/sales/orders/create/items.phtml
- app/design/adminhtml/default/default/sales/orders/create/items/grid.phtml

If you want to add some JS logic to the "Add Products" button, you may want to look at the
getButtonsHtml() method of Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Items where you will be able to update the 'onclick' of the $addButtonData array.

If you want to add some JS loic to the Update Items and Qty's button, you may tweak the app/design/adminhtml/default/default/sales/orders/create/items/grid.phtml file between lines 428 (Magento CE 1.4.1.1)